# django View - 'Comment' object has no attribute 'comments'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to get my comments to be deleted but when I run the code the following error shows up:

[image]

my comment_delete views:

```
class CommentDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.comments == self.request.user
```

models.py Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comments',
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_list')
```

Comment: `obj` is a `Comment` model, not an `Article`, hence it has no `.comments`...

Answer (score 1):

`obj` is a `Comment` model, not an `Article`, hence it has no `.comments` attribute, but even if that was the case, it would be a `RelatedManager` for `Comment`s, so it makes no sense to compare that with `request.user`.

If the `Comment` is related to the user, you need to work with a `ForeignKey` that injects the user into the `Comment`, so:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comments',
    )
    body = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='comments',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

then you can filter with:

```
class CommentDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('article_list')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            user=self.request.user
        )
```

---

> **Note**: The [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) should return a *canonical* URL, that means that for two different model objects the URL should be different and thus point to a view specific for that model object. You thus should not return the same URL for all model objects.

Comment: thanks but even with the changes I'm getting this error: Reverse for 'comment_delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[0-9]+)/delete/\\Z']

Comment: @A.z575: that's because the expression you use in `{% url 'comment_delete' foo %}` has an invalid expression for `foo` (for example a non-existing variable).